# java: searching for the minimum in a 2d array and giving back the position of the minimum (row and coumn)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a 2d array from which I need to know the minimum value. It is possible that the number is more than once inside the array, in this case the first one of them will be the minimum.
Afterwards I will need to know at which position (row and column) the minimum value was found.

I already have the part where I am searching for the minimum, but I am stuck with the exact position. Below you will see my code so far.

```
double lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[1][1]);

for(int r = 1; r<excelMatrix.length-1; r++){

   for(int c = 2; c<excelMatrix[r].length; c++){

      double number = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
         if(lowest > number) lowest = number;
   }
}
System.out.print(lowest);
```

I hope someone might be able to help me with this problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well, why don't you just save `r` and `c` values somewhere when you encounter the minimum?

Comment: @mszymborski I am new to java and did not know how to do that. It was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indxing in Java is `0-based`, so you are ignoring the first row completely.
After that you are ignoring all the elements in the first column except `excelMatrix[1][1]`. The correct implementation will be:

```
double lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[0][0]);
int row = 0, column = 0;

for(int r = 0; r< excelMatrix.length; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c<excelMatrix[r].length; c++) {
        double number = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
        if(lowest > number) {
            lowest = number;
            row = r, column = c;
        }
    }
}
System.out.print(lowest + " at row: " + row + "and column: " + column);
```

Comment: thank you for your quick help! In the other row and column I have text for the better understanding of the excel sheet, which is not needed for the matrix in java.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have saved `excelMatrix` using 1-based indexing, the following should work:

Add two variables to save the position of the minimum number, say `lowestRow` and `lowestCol`.
Code:

```
double lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[1][1]);
int lowestRow = 1;
int lowestCol = 1;

for(int r = 1; r<excelMatrix.length; r++){

   for(int c = 1; c<excelMatrix[r].length; c++){

      double number = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
         if(lowest > number) {
             lowest = number;
             lowestRow = r;
             lowestCol = c;
         }
   }
}
System.out.println(lowest);
System.out.println("Row Position of minimum element is" + lowestRow);
System.out.println("Column Position of minimum element is" + lowestCol);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!